# Explanation for equivalent looking statements returning different results after bitshift

Tags: c, bit-shift

Looking for an understanding of what is happening here as both statements appear the same.

So while the `c >> 1` output is what I was expecting, shifting the wrapped uint in-place changes the result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    uint16_t a, b, c;
    a = 20180;
    b = 4106;
    c = b - a;
    printf("%hu\n", c >> 1);
    printf("%hu\n", (b - a) >> 1);
    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

> 24731
>
> 57499

What causes this behaviour?

Thanks.

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior. The compiler warning: *"format specifies type 'unsigned short' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]"*

Comment: "*shifting the wrapped uint in-place*" That's not what `(b - a) >> 1` does, in particular `b - a` is not a "*wrapped uint*". That would be `(uint16_t)(b - a) >> 1` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "in-place" operation promotes a and b to int, and the result will also be an int that you then shift.
In your assignment of c = b - a, the operation is first promoted to int operation, executed, then type casted back to uint (to be set in c).
The keyword to search for is "integer promotion"

Comment: There is no cast to `uint` or `uint16_t` in `c = b - a; `. A cast is an explicit operator.

Comment: You are correct. Wrong terminology used, instead of `type casted back` maybe I should use masked/converted/cut. Either way, the operation is performed on ints and then stored in the smaller type.